# How to skip count by 10 to 1000 in python (using a loop)

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to display numbers counting by 10s up to 1000 without having to type all that out.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
for num in range(1, 1001):
    print("num")
```

but that just gets you a list of all the numbers. What should I do if I want it to show as 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, etc.?

Comment: Take a closer look at the documentation for `range()` - it takes an optional third parameter, for the step size.

Comment: @OysterShucker that would yield 1, 11, 21, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Python range() function comes with a third optional 'step' parameter that lets you do what you're looking for:

```
for num in range(0, 1001, 10): 
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your start to be 1, stop to be 1001 and also omit the step parameter, you can add an `if` statement (which is more coding though):

```
for num in range(1, 1001):
    if num % 10 == 0:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

range has 3 arguments `range(start, end, step)`. To start at 10, end at 1000, and increment by 10 while printing each number on a new line, you can use:

`print(*range(10, 1001, 10), sep='\n')`

`*` is the unpack operator. It will unpack the individual results of an iterable, and in this case, use them as arguments. `sep='\n'` is indicating that print should separate all of those arguments with a new line.

Answer (score -1):

the range () function has a syntax of lowest num, highest num, and ***step count***.
You could edit your code to be like this :
for number in range (0, 1001, 10) :